# Ancestry path with 'path_id' or 'group_id" and 'level' in graph SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, recursion, grouping

I have the following table:

```
pairID  source_issue_id   destination_issue_id
----------------------------------------------
1          J                I
2          B                C
3          J                M
4          F                I
5          A                B
6          A                E
7          N                O
8          J                L
9          C                D
10         P                Q
11         G                H
12         B                F
13         L                K
14         C                N
15         A                G
16         E                F
```

Representing nodes in a graph.

I'm not using `pairID`, since does not seem useful.

I want to get the ancestor path for all nodes, the level at which each pair occurs, the full path, and the 'path group'

So far I've used the following code:

```
;with auxPairs as 
(
    select 
        1 as lvl, 
        b.source_issue_id, 
        b.destination_issue_id, 
        cast((b.source_issue_id+ '|' + b.destination_issue_id) as varchar(50)) as "full_path"
    from 
        Pairs2 b
    where
        b.source_issue_id not in (select destination_issue_id from Pairs2)

    union all

    select 
        lvl+1 as lvl, 
        c.source_issue_id, 
        c.destination_issue_id,
        CAST((a.full_path + '|' + c.destination_issue_id) as varchar(50)) as "full_path" 
    from 
        Pairs2 c
    join 
        auxPairs a on a.destination_issue_id = c.source_issue_id
)
```

That returns the 'connection level' of two nodes (e.g. A|B is level 1) in `lvl`, the source and destination nodes and the full path (up to that pair), e.g.

```
lvl   source   destination   full_path
--------------------------------------
1     A        B             A|B
2     B        C             A|B|C
3     C        N             A|B|C|N
4     N        O             A|B|C|N|O
1     A        B             A|B
2     B        C             A|B|C
3     C        D             A|B|C|D
....
```

and so on for each path in the tree.

I need to add to this a `Path_id` or `group_id` so I get:

```
path_id   lvl   source   destination   full_path
------------------------------------------------
1         1     A        B             A|B
1         2     B        C             A|B|C
1         3     C        N             A|B|C|N
1         4     N        O             A|B|C|N|O
2         1     A        B             A|B
2         2     B        C             A|B|C
2         3     C        D             A|B|C|D
....
```

meaning that the nodes with the same path_id are connected in a given order

NOTE: The alphabetical 'fake" order will not work with actual data. I need to use the `path_id` and `lvl` to establish the partial order within the path.

Comment: I ran your data through a simple graph visualization program and there are multiple paths to the F node (both B and E are parents). What would you expect the output to be for that node?

Comment: A|E|F|I
   A|B|F|I     

Because of this, I think I need to do the grouping from the bottom up
Thanks!

Comment: A|E|F|I,   
    A|B|F|I     

Because of this, I think I need to do the grouping from the bottom up
Thanks!